# Create fixed header table html

Tags: html

I am creating a fixed header table, but the header and the data do not seem to be aligned. The table is created dynamically. Here is the sample of the generated html -

What do you think I should do ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title></title>
    <style>
        /*spreadsheet*/

        .row:nth-child(odd)
        {
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        }
        /* Similarly we can define another rule for even */

        .bodyTable td
        {
            white-space: normal; /*text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
            overflow: hidden;
            word-spacing: normal;
            font-family: Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .bodyTable tr
        {
            height: 20px;
        }

        .bodyTable tr:hover
        {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }

        .headerTable
        {
            text-align: justify;
            vertical-align: middle;
            word-spacing: normal;
            border-spacing: 0px;            
            border-style: solid;
            caption-side: top;
            word-wrap:break-word;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .th
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }

        .scroll
        {
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tableTag">
        <table width="1903px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="headerTable" width="1878px">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                sample1
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                sample2
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                sample3
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                sample
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                testsample
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                column2
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                column3
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                column4
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="scroll" width="1903px" style="height: 200px;">
                        <table class="bodyTable" border="0" width="1878px" height="200px" style="table-layout: fixed">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="row">
                                    <td>
                                        54.29204
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        76.806827
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        31.127742
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        -0.409866
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2.965601
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        6.696099
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        - 0.947771
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        9.713368
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row">
                                    <td>
                                        72.082179
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        68.104432
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        16.588382
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        - 0.564589
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        5.759212
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        7.916862
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        - 0.706712
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        3.840213
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because table headers are a saperate table (th) .You have put inside the main table element or play with inline style to succeed that.

Comment: If I put them inside main table, I dont think it will provide me with fixed style headers

Comment: http://www.fixedheadertable.com

Comment: Here is a hack I was thinking of , Create the header cells as part of the inner table. Once the inner table loads , compute the width of each cell given by the browser and use it to define the width of the header table ? BTW I am using d3js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution you could do is if know that every table will have 8 columns in it (like you have in your example code) you can set the header-table columns and the body-table columns to the same widths so they align properly. In this case with 8 columns you could use `width:12.5%` so each of the columns is the same width. The CSS code would look something like this:

```
.headerTable th {
     background-color: lightblue;
     width:12.5%;
}
.bodyTable td {
     white-space: normal; /*text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
     overflow: hidden;
     word-spacing: normal;
     font-family: Sans-Serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     text-align: right;
     width:12.5%;
}
```